# derive differential form

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{l}{mr^2} \frac{dr}{d\theta})-\frac{l^2}{mr^3}=f(r)$$

I have to prove it is equal to

[image]

by taking $u=\dfrac{1}{r}$.

---

$$\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{l}{mr^2}\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}-\frac{l^2}{mr^3}=f(r)$$
$$\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}=\frac{mr^4}{l^2}f(r)+\frac{1}{r}$$
$$\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}-\frac{1}{r}=\frac{mr^4}{l^2}f(r)$$

I just can write that $du=-\frac{1}{r^2dr}$ I can't see how it will work for my equation.

Comment: $\frac{d}{d\theta }\left(\frac{l}{mr^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta }\right)=-\frac{l}{m r^3}\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta }\right)^2+\frac{l}{mr^2}\frac{d^2 r}{d\theta ^2}$, and not what you wrote. Also, $du=-\frac{1}{r^2}dr$ and not what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

We have $u=\dfrac{1}{r},$ so $r=\dfrac{1}{u}$ and $\dfrac{dr}{d\theta}=-\dfrac{1}{u^2}\dfrac{du}{d\theta}$ by the chain rule and thus substituting we have

$$\frac{l}{r^2}\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{l}{mr^2} \frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)-\frac{l^2}{mr^3}=f(r)$$
$$lu^2\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{lu^2}{m}\left(-\frac{1}{u^2}\frac{du}{d\theta}\right)\right)-\frac{l^2}{m}u^3=f\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$$
$$-\frac{l^2u^{2}}{m}\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}-\frac{l^2}{m}u^3=f\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$$
$$\frac{d^{2}u}{d\theta^2}+u=-\frac{m}{l^2}\frac{1}{u^2}f\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)=-\frac{m}{l^2}\frac{d}{du}V\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$$

where $\dfrac{d}{du}V\left(\dfrac{1}{u}\right)=\dfrac{1}{u^2}f\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$